# the ratio of the derivative of a holomorphic function over itself

Tags: complex-analysis, holomorphic-functions

Let $h(x)$ be a holomorphic complex function. Is it true that the ratio :$h'(x)/h(x)$ is holomorphic as well? (please explain why)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It won't necessarily be a holomorphic function. Actually, anywhere $h(x)=0$ it wont be holomorphic.

For example for $h(x)=x$, 
$h^{'}(x)/h(x) = 1/x$ which is not holomorphic at $x=0$.

It will be a meromorphic function tho